# How to hook a private framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, hook, jailbreak, cydia-substrate

I am trying to make an jailbreak tweak that requires hooking into some private frameworks such as SpringBoardUI.framework. How would I do so? I've already tried adding 'TweakName' PRIVATEFRAMEWORKS = SpringBoardUI in the makefile with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from adding `TweakName_PRIVATEFRAMEWORKS = SpringBoardUI` to your Makefile, you need to set your filter to that framework (`com.apple.SpringBoardUIFramework`).

Comment: after that should I #import <SpringBoardUI/SpringBoardUI.h>

Comment: Considering that it is a private framework, it is very unlikely to find a complete working set of headers. Usually developers just write a small @interface containing the minimum characteristics of the class being hooked